# Open-Atrium Toolbar

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

I have two blue prints for the **space** content type in OA. On the toolbar dropdown i want to show only the spaces created using the **default** blue print. AO uses the ***oa_core_get_groups_by_user_access***(found in OA core module in the **oa_core.util.inc** file) to pull all spaces a use subscribed to. I want to alter this function to show only spaces created using the default blue print by altering the query used in this function.

All my attempts to do so have failed probably because i don't understand the drupal database abstraction queries. Can someone help me with the piece of code i can add to this function to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: (this is in response to the comment above)
I tried addid the following lines but it didn't change a thing.
// show only default spaces
    $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_oa_space_type', 's', "s.bundle = n.type");
    $query->condition('s.field_oa_space_type_tid',1); 

So @dayuloli if you know a way i can improve my query please help. Thanks

Comment: Please add what you've tried in the question itself. I don't use Open Atrium, so I can't really help much. I was just moderating questions and commented to suggest how you can improve it

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. To show only the default spaces in the dropdown, you have to make changes to the **oa_core_get_titles** function in the ***oa_core_util.inc*** file of **oa_core**.

Add the following line below **line 641** of that particular file.
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_oa_space_type','t','n.nid=t.entity_id');
$query->condition('t.field_oa_space_type_tid',1);

This filters out only spaces created using the default space.